# How do I extract the signing certificate in ACS for WCF?

Tags: wcf, certificate, federated-identity, azure-appfabric

Due to a [bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazureconnectivity/thread/7bc5d93b-05ca-4f61-802f-d1cbb22c9d6a) in either FedUtil, or ACSLabs, I am adapting this WCF [AppFabric labs sample](http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Certificate%20Authentication&referringTitle=Samples) to use the default signing certificate of ACS instead of a custom one.

Question: How do I extract the signing cert used in the ACS Labs for use within WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need the signing cert for?

I think what's probably happening, is that ACS WS-FederationMetadata is not being updated with your custom certificate. But this should very simple to fix: if you own the cert, you know the thumbprint too. Just replace the value in the web.config and try again.

So, to summarize:

1- If you use a custom cert: upload to ACS, configure ACS to use the cert for signing, run FedUtil and then make sure the web.config of your app has your cert thumbprint.

2- If you use the default signing cert, just run FedUtil and everything should just work.

Comment: I got this part working about 45 min ago with the help of Azure PSS Support.  I had to import the certificate as a "primary service" cert so that the Fedmetadata updates the trusted issuer.  When it comes to signing certs, I'm confused about the intended usage of per-relying party certs, and the primary checkbox in relation to Active and Passive WCF/ WIF clients